# Eclipse Layout: static instead of relative values?

Tags: android, eclipse, layout

I have a layout with two Buttons. One button is in the Center of the left half, and the other button is in the Center of the right side. But I use relative values (left="60dp" etc.). How can I have the same result with static values? Because I don't want to create an extra layout for every screen size...

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="42dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
    android:text="Button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Button02"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="60dp"
    android:text="Button" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <LinearLayout
     android:orientation=horizontal
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">
     <LinearLayout
      android:orientation=horizontal
      android:layout_width="0"
      android:weight="50"
      android:layout_height="match_parent">
     <Button
     android:id="@+id/button1"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="75dp"
     android:gravity="center"
     android:text="Button" />
     </LinearLayout>
     <LinearLayout
      android:orientation=horizontal
      android:layout_width="0"
      android:weight="50"
      android:layout_height="match_parent">
     <Button
     android:id="@+id/Button02"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="75dp"
     android:gravity="center"
     android:text="Button" />
 </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```